# Spark + write to Hive table + workaround

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Am trying to understand the pros and cons of one of the approaches that I am hearing frequently in my workspace.

Spark while writing data to Hive table (InsertInto) does following

1. Write to the staging folder
2. Move data to hive table using output committer.

Now I see people are complaining that the above 2 step approach is time-consuming and hence resorting to

```
    1) Write files directly to HDFS

    2) Refresh metastore for Hive
```

And I see people reporting a lot of improvement with this approach.

But somehow I am not yet convinced that it's the safe and right method. is it not a tradeoff for Automiticy? (Either full table write or no write)

What if the executor that's writing a file to HDFS crashes? I don't see a way to completely revert the half-done writes.

I also think Spark would have done this if it was the right way to do, isn't it?

Are my questions valid? Do you see any good in the above approach? Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% right cause in hive v3 you could only access hive data with hive driver in order not to break new transaction machine.

Even if you are using hive2 you should at least keep in mind that you would not be able to access the data directly as soon as you upgrade.